# python unpack buffer data

Tags: python, linux, tcp, dhcp

I am using the `rlm_python` module in radius and its get the DHCP location `option82` from coovachilli in hex or binary format.

Catching it as a string shows as this value `\001\027\002\025\001+\001\024`, but looks the value which python shows is  truncated, as the `option82` contains `suboptions`  encoded in `TLVs-type,length,values` which means the field starts with type `0x01(circuit ID, per RFC 3046)`, followed by a one byte length.

Any idea how I can catch this and unpack the options properly?

I have unpacked the string using `struct.unpack` but is not meaningful..as it does not tell about the packed `suboptions` in `option82` field.

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, May  5 2011, 16:39:10) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from struct import *
>>> unpack('=hhl',"\001\027\002\025\001+\001\024" )
(5889, 5378, 335620865)
```

any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Coovachilli is compiled with `--locationopt82` and it sends location as an attribute, something like this...

```
rad_recv: Accounting-Request packet from host 10.66.53.49 port 53178, id=101, length=342
        ChilliSpot-Version = "1.3.0"
        ChilliSpot-Acct-View-Point = ChilliSpot-Client-View-Point
        Event-Timestamp = "Apr 18 2013 11:59:16 BST"
        User-Name = "3C-D0-F8-4A-05-68"
        Acct-Input-Octets = 0
        Acct-Output-Octets = 22851
        Acct-Input-Gigawords = 0
        Acct-Output-Gigawords = 0
        Acct-Input-Packets = 0
        Acct-Output-Packets = 370
        Acct-Session-Time = 5401
        ChilliSpot-Session-State = Authorized
        Acct-Status-Type = Interim-Update
        Acct-Session-Id = "516fbceb00000002"
        Framed-IP-Address = 10.75.33.46
        NAS-Port-Type = Wireless-802.11
        NAS-Port = 2
        NAS-Port-Id = "00000002"
        Calling-Station-Id = "3C-D0-F8-4A-05-68"
        Called-Station-Id = "00-50-56-B7-66-00"
        NAS-IP-Address = 10.75.32.7
        ChilliSpot-Location = "\001\030\002\026\001+\001\024"
        ChilliSpot-Location-Change-Count = 15
        NAS-Identifier = "VLAN299-REGENT"
        WISPr-Location-ID = "isocc=GR,cc=44,ac=01200,network=mywifi,my_Network_regent"
        WISPr-Location-Name = "REGENT"
```

the freeradius has the `rlm_python` module which looks for accounting requests

```
def accounting(p):
    file = open("/tmp/test.log","a")
    username = None
    chillilocation = None
    output = StringIO.StringIO()

    for t in p:
        if t[0] == 'User-Name':
            username = t[1]
        elif t[0] == 'ChilliSpot-Location':
            chillilocation = t[1]a
             output.write(t[1])


    content = output.getvalue()


    file.write("I am being called in radius accouting section as %s and location is %s \n" % (username,content))
    file.close()
    print "---Accounting---"
    radiusd.radlog(radiusd.L_INFO, '*** radlog call in accounting (0) ***')
    print
    print p
    return radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK
```

i have tried storing the ChilliSpot-Location in `string` and `stringIO`, unpacked using struct with no avail, It looks like its in TLV format...

any ideas how to strip it out?

Comment: How do you catch the value as a string using rlm_python and coovachilli?

Comment: i have updated it above

Comment: Not sure about the whole thing but `ChilliSpot-Location` is supposed to be a human-readable string. See [specs](http://wiki-robin.meshroot.com/@api/deki/files/220/=dictionary.chillispot) and [an example](http://coova.org/node/4170) (Browse down to somewhere in the middle where it says `RADIUS Access-Request from CoovaChilli`)

Answer (score 0):

Unpack does not unpacks to "meaningful" values. It unpacks the string as a sequence of number fields, so that the size of each field is specified by each char of the format string (numbers preceding letters are multipliers).

Shouldn't the unpack use octet-sized fields?

> >>> unpack('=8B',"\001\027\002\025\001+\001\024")
>   (1, 23, 2, 21, 1, 43, 1, 20)
>   # Or maybe '+' is a separator (43):
>   >>> unpack('=6Bh',"\001\027\002\025\001+\001\024")
>   (1, 23, 2, 21, 1, 43, 5121)

The first byte may be a circuit suboption code (unpack()[0]==1) with a strangelly high size of 23, meaning we didn't get the whole suboption value. But we may also have only the contained value of a suboption with size == 10, or 8 bytes of content.

I'm not so sure that an option 82 should contain a readable string, though "ChilliSpot-Location" does. RFC3046 indicates the circuit suboption is expected to contain things like "Router interface number", port numbers and other numerical values. But that property of rad_recv really came from a 82 option?

Comment: thanks for the reply, according to coova it is from the option 82 field on dhcp packet, if the unpack shows only the size, then where is the actual content, obviously it represents something...